# if decremented field value is negative return zero in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a simple user model with a balance field and want to create a penalty system for users.  Here transaction.amount can be a negative value too, and I don't want to have profiles with a negative balance.

how I can update balance with condition if result is negative return 0

```
db.profiles.update(
   { _id: transaction.receiver  },
   { $inc: { balance: decimal(transaction.amount) }} // if result is less than 0 return zero 
)
```

Comment: what is your mongodb version ? So you don't want to store negative values in `balance` field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Starting in MongoDB 4.2, you can use the aggregation pipeline for
>   update operations.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/

Which means you can update the document while you can also check the current document's value. But the aggregation pipeline for update operation doesn't support `$inc` operator, so you will have to modify the update a bit.
For your case it would be:

```js
db.profiles.update(
  { _id: transaction.receiver  },
  [{
    $set: {
      balance: {
        $cond: [
          { $lte: ['$balance', -decimal(transaction.amount)] }, // balance + amount <= 0
          0, 
          { $add: ['$balance', decimal(transaction.amount)] }
        ]
      }
    }
  }]
)
```

If you happen to use an earlier version of MongoDB, you can split your update query into 2 operations, using the balance as part of your condition

```
db.profiles.update(
   { _id: transaction.receiver, balance: { $lte: -decimal(transaction.amount) }  },
   { $set: { balance: 0 } }
)

db.profiles.update(
   { _id: transaction.receiver, balance: { $gt: -decimal(transaction.amount) }  },
   { $inc: { balance: decimal(transaction.amount) } }
)
```